# Get spark application id based on oozie job id

Tags: hadoop, oozie, oozie-workflow

I am trying to get spark application id from unix based on oozie id. I am able to get map reduce job id when i try with `oozie -info <oozie_id>@<action_name>`. How can I get spark application id

Answer (score 2):

**From Web UI:**

to get to a spark application log,

1. go to `oozie's web console` and find the `hadoop job Id` of that `action` such as : `job_202007171535_0223`

   you can get app id by replacing `job` with `application` in job id, such as `application_202007171535_0223` from `job_202007171535_0223`
2. using the hadoop job/application id from step 1, go to `Yarn Resource Manager WebUI` to look into that `logs`(common for hive/hadoop/spark jobs which are managed by YARN)
3. access to `Spark UI` for the debugging DAG,Stages,fine tuning using the app id, such as `application_202007171535_0223`

**From command line interface, the above steps would be:**

1. Run oozie cmd to get hadoop job id:

   `oozie job -info <your job id here>`
2. look for `External Id` in the output, such as : `job_202007171535_0223`

   you can get app id by replacing `job` with `application` in job id, such as `application_202007171535_0223` from `job_202007171535_0223`
3. Run the below YARN cmd to get YARN job logs (common for hive/hadoop/spark jobs which are managed by YARN):

   `yarn logs -applicationId <your app id here>`

Comment: In the answer u provided job_202007171535_0223 is id for mapreduce or SPARK one..

Comment: `job_202007171535_0223` - is for mapreduce `application_202007171535_0223` is for spark

Comment: This doesn't work to retrieve the real applicationId for Spark job... Even if you replace job_ for application_

Answer (score 0):

There are two IDs for a oozie Spark action. And both aren’t same.

1. Oozie launcher job ID.
2. Spark job ID associated with the launcher.

To get both the ids:

1. `oozie -info <oozie_id>@<action_name>` will give you oozie launcher ID.
2. `oozie job -info <oozie-launcher-id> | grep racking` this will give you spark application id using oozie launcher ID that you will get from the 1<sup>st</sup> command.

***Note:** `grep racking` actually stands for `grep tracking` but at the moment I forgot if it starts with capital `T` or small `t` but `racking` will do the job.*